# MPMoviePlayerViewController protected URL from yahoo hosted site using setDefaultCredential

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using similar code as mentioned in `MPMoviePlayerViewController` documentation. But it's not working. It says "you are not authorized..". My server is hosted on Yahoo. Url is something like [this.](http://www.someurl.com/tmp/somevideo.mp4)

Code is below

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] 
                           initWithUser:@"abc" 
                           password:@"xyz"
                           persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

 NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                     initWithHost:@"www.someurl.com"
                                     port:80
                                     protocol:@"http"
                                     realm:@"tmp"

   authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];

[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential
                                                forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

 [protectionSpace release];
 [credential release];
  MPMoviePlayerViewController *movie = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the same as the UIWebView access you would first open up an NSURLConnection and pass the credential in the relevant delegate methods then once you get a response you cancel the connection and then start the MPMoviePlayerViewController with the connection.